# Chrome not setting checkboxes to checked on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a page that filters a list according the checkboxes selected.  A click event on each checkbox  makes an ajax call to the server with the form data from the checkboxes and returns filtered items.
This is a simple page so all settings are lost when user moves to another page.

I want to remember checkbox form data in a cookie and on page load want to read that cookie to query server for new data and set relevant checkboxes to 'checked'.

To do this I have modified the checkbox click event to write the form data to a cookie as well as call server to fetch results.  This works fine.

I've also written a jQuery function that is called on page load after `document.ready` to read that cookie. This works well in **FireFox** and **Edge** but in **Chrome** it is completely unreliable; the list is always filtered (ajax call returns data based on cookie values) but the checkboxes are sometimes `checked` and sometimes not checked.

Data in the cookie is stored like this:

```
industrySectors=1695&apples=4135&oranges=2141&pears=2136
```

This is the function (fine in FF and Edge but not Chrome).

```
function SetMemberListFilterFromCookie() {
    if ($(".MemberListPage").length > 0) {
        var cookieValue = readCookie("searchFilterCookie"));
        if (cookieValue) {
            getMembers(cookieValue); 

            var array1 = cookieValue.split("&");
            var array2 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= array1.length - 1; i++) {
                array2.push(array1[i].split("="));
            }
            // This section seems to be an issue in CHROME
            // Checkboxes are not always checked on page load
            for (var c = 0; c < array2.length; c++) {
                var id = array2[c][0] + "-" + array2[c][1];
                $("#" + id).prop("checked", true);
            }
            
            // checkbox panels are initially hidden on page
            // if any checkboxes within a filterPanel have been checked, the filterPanel is opened.
            var filterPanels = $(".filter-panel ul");
            filterPanels.each(function() {
                var checked = $(this).find("input:checked");
                if (checked.length > 0) {
                    animateFilterSection($(this).prev());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

function animateFilterSection(btn) {
    btn.next("ul").slideToggle({
        duration: 100,
        complete: function() {
            btn.toggleClass("plus minus");
        }
    });
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === " ")
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0)
            return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Anyone know what is going wrong in Chrome? Is cookies the right approach?

Comment: Is readCookie() a user-defined function or k Javascript keyword. I've never heard of it

Comment: It's a user defined function.

Comment: Where your function is defined. I didn't see it anywhere in the script.

Comment: Added now. This part works fine as the function returns correct data from server without issue (getMembers). This means readCookie works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I managed to get the above code to work consistently across all browsers was to change the for loop to:

```
    for (var c = 0; c < array2.length; c++) {
        var id = array2[c][0] + "-" + array2[c][1];
        $("#" + id).attr("checked", true);
        $("#" + id).prop("checked", true);
    }
```

Feels a bit hacky but using just `$("#" + id).prop("checked", true);` refused to work consistently in Chrome.